# Cannot pair ssh key between mac (Yosemite) and server(ubuntu)

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ssh

Alright, I know this question has been asked quite often. However, I looked and tried every single one of them without success. Here are the complete steps of what I did:

1. I created a pair of public and private key without any passphrase password using the following command:

*Command*

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t rsa -f id_rsa -P ""
```

2. Once in my .ssh folder, I checked to make sure the permissions were okay, still on my mac

*Permissions*

```
-rw-------   1 etienne  staff  1675 30 jan 10:13 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 etienne  staff   418 30 jan 10:13 id_rsa.pub
```

And the .ssh folder:

```
drwx------    7 etienne  staff      238 30 jan 10:25 .ssh
```

3. Then, I went on the server, and verified that the sshd_config in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` had the lines

*config file*

```
RSAAuthentication yes   
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The complete sshd_config is located at the end

4. On the server, I copied the public key located inside the id_rsa.pub on my mac, to the authorized_keys file on my server in `/home/imatech/.ssh/`
5. The permissions of the authorized_keys file on my server, is:

*Permission*

```
-rw-r--r--  1 imatech imatech  172 Jan 30 10:19 authorized_keys
```

6. The permissions of the .ssh folder is:

*Permission*

```
drwx------  2 imatech imatech  4096 Jan 30 10:19 .ssh
```

7. Now when, on my mac, I try to access imatech@server.com with this command: `ssh -v imatech@server.com`, it does not seam to be able to authenticate with my private key:

*Command*:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ima-tech.ca [168.144.170.64] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/etienne/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/etienne/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/etienne/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/etienne/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA cf:45:23:53:41:6f:7b:3b:2d:1c:87:38:64:1f:5e:1b
debug1: Host 'ima-tech.ca' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/etienne/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/etienne/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/etienne/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I have no clue, everything seems fine...

---

**sshd_config of the server (Ubuntu)**

```
    # Package generated configuration file
    # See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

    # What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
    Port 22
    # Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
    #ListenAddress ::
    #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
    Protocol 2
    # HostKeys for protocol version 2
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
    #Privilege Separation is turned on for security
    UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

    # Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
    KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
    ServerKeyBits 768

    # Logging
    SyslogFacility AUTH
    LogLevel INFO

    # Authentication:
    LoginGraceTime 120
    PermitRootLogin yes
    StrictModes yes

    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

    # Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
    IgnoreRhosts yes
    # For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
    RhostsRSAAuthentication no
    # similar for protocol version 2
    HostbasedAuthentication no
    # Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
    #IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

    # To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
    PermitEmptyPasswords no

    # Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
    # some PAM modules and threads)
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

    # Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
    #PasswordAuthentication yes

    # Kerberos options
    #KerberosAuthentication no
    #KerberosGetAFSToken no
    #KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
    #KerberosTicketCleanup yes

    # GSSAPI options
    #GSSAPIAuthentication no
    #GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

    X11Forwarding yes
    X11DisplayOffset 10
    PrintMotd no
    PrintLastLog yes
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    #UseLogin no

    #MaxStartups 10:30:60
    #Banner /etc/issue.net

    # Allow client to pass locale environment variables
    AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

    Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

    # Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
    # and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
    # be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
    # PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
    # PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
    # the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
    # If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
    # PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
    # and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
    UsePAM yes


    #Testing the use of the https to access the server via ssh behind proxy
    Port 2222
```

**sshd_config of the mac**

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.89 2013/02/06 00:20:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# See sshd_config(5) for details on setting the Port and Listen values on Mac OS X
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords both PasswordAuthentication and
# ChallengeResponseAuthentication must be set to "no".
#PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# Also, PAM will deny null passwords by default.  If you need to allow
# null passwords, add the " nullok" option to the end of the
# securityserver.so line in /etc/pam.d/sshd.
#UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#XauthLocation xauth # Default is to search $PATH (set by launchd(8)).  It is recommended that a full path be provided.
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox      # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got that resolved by installing ssh-copy-id using homebrew:

```
brew install ssh-copy-id
```

Then, I simply used the command:

```
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub imatech@server.com
```

Really weird...